# How do I set my Canon 600D for Long Exposure?

Tags: canon, dslr, long-exposure, camera-settings, bulb-mode

I have a Canon 600d. I need to have a long exposure. What settings should be used to achieve a long exposure in my camera? I tried searching and most of them say bulb mode. I don't see it in my camera. Any suggestions on how to achieve long exposure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Take a look at page 100 of the manual.** It explains how to use Bulb mode.

Put the camera into Manual(M) mode using the top dial, then turn the dial to the left to select BULB.

You can also use an [intervalometer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intervalometer) to capture long exposures of varying times more accurately then in the bulb mode.

Comment: Why buy an intervalometer when most people have a stopwatch ;) (actual watch or on their mobile). By the time you get to bulb mode, a few seconds here or there make no noticeable difference to the exposure.

Comment: @DetlevCM - I don't use a intervalometer to get exact down to the second long exposures, but I do use it so I don't have to use a stopwatch. Use whatever you want. I have an intervalometer with me anyways in my bag.

Comment: I used to whistle "British Grenadiers", which takes exactly 32 seconds at a standard marching pace (something us military types can gauge to an eerie degree of accuracy after years of parade square silliness). Really long exposures are usually done in the dark, and luminous dials had gone out while illuminated dials just *weren't* yet. A locking cable release (or a T mode) makes a huge difference for the many-minute variety.

Answer (score 6):

Get [Magic Lantern](http://www.magiclantern.fm/index.html).

Opens up a whole load of neat stuff including an intervalometer. And it's free!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what [dpollitt wrote](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/29570/1772) about using Bulb mode, you may want to consider **buying a remote control/shutter release**.

It looks like the Canon RS-60E3 will work with the EOS 600D, but there are aftermarket variants as well, and you should double-check compatibility to be certain. The specific model number Canon unit will almost certainly be listed in the manual under accessories.

A remote control will allow you to keep the shutter depressed, or even lock it in a "down" position, without risking vibration to the camera body, thus helping significantly with long exposure photography. This becomes even more pronounced with mirror lock-up (don't know if the 600D has that feature), as it can nearly completely eliminate camera vibration.

Comment: That is why I brought up the intervalometer. You can get an aftermarket intervalometer for under $20USD, so if possible I recommend getting that and not buying a $15 remote first!